# Putting an object in a List doesn't work with int

Tags: c#, .net, class

Why do I get this error?: *"The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(int)' has some invalid arguments"*

*"Argument 1: cannot convert from 'tentamen130328Tarning.Tarning' to 'int'"*

I have used a list like this before but with string and that worked.

The code:

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> _Tarning = new List<int>();

            int xVal = int.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("Skriv hur många tärningar du vill kasta:"));
            int yVal = int.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("Skriv hur många sidor du vill att tärningen ska ha:"));

            _Tarning.Add(new Tarning(xVal,yVal));

        }
    }
}

        class Tarning
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            static int _xVal, _yVal;
            static int[,] tarning = new int[_xVal, _yVal];
            int slumpa()
        {
              for (int i = 0; i <tarning.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j  = 0; j < tarning.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        tarning[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, _yVal); 
                    }
                }
        }

            public Tarning(int Xval, int Yval)
            {
                Xval = _xVal;
                Yval = _yVal;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your `Tarning` content?

Comment: Pls provide the declaration for _Tarning obj and Tarning class

Comment: Is `_Tarning` defined as `List<int> _Tarning`? If so, a constructor of `Tarning(xVal,yVal)` returns type `Tarning`, not `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `List<int> _Tarning = new List<int>();`

to

`List<Tarning> _Tarning = new List<Tarning>();`

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please click on the tick mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

You declared the _Tarning variable as:

```
List<int> _Tarning = new List<int>();
```

A Tarning is not an int and cannot implicitly be converted to an int so the compiler complains that it can't add the Tarning (or convert it to an int.

Change the declaration of the list.

```
List<Tarning> _Tarning = new List<Tarning>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of your list must be `Tarning` type not `int`. So answer is :

```
List<Tarning> _Tarning = new List<Tarning>();
```

instead of:

```
List<int> _Tarning = new List<int>();
```